# POST to GET Redirection

Tags: java, spring, jsp, http

On jsp page After session expiration if a user performs some DB operations the Post url HTTP status shows as 302 which should redirect to my logout Page but as it's a GET call to logout it is not being redirected.

How to redirect from POST Http status 302 to GET or what can be the other way to achieve this?

Comment: you may possibly use [filters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm), also see [Essentials of Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)

Comment: Do you have servlets or use Spring MVC's controllers?

Comment: i am using Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

Some comments/suggestion:

- When the server responds with [`HTTP 302`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) additionally it also sends a `Location` header which browser reads and makes another `GET` request.
- This is how it typically works. So please make sure that when you send  `HTTP 302` you also send a `Location` header in response and then rest of the things will be handled by the browser.

Please note that here I have take liberty to assume that you can change server side code which sends `HTTP 302`. Let me know if its otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session Filter like :

```
      public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

        private ArrayList<String> urlList;

        public void destroy() {
        }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            String url = request.getServletPath();
            boolean allowedRequest = false;

            if(urlList.contains(url)) {
                allowedRequest = true;
            }

            if (!allowedRequest) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                if (null == session) {
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                }
            }
    }

            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
}
```

and by making an entry in webl.xml

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        net.viralpatel.servlet.filter.SessionFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
        <param-value>index.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Or hide the details via placing following entry in web.xml:

```
  <error-page>
        <error-code>302</error-code>
        <location>/302ErrorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```